# How do I align a banner above buttons

Tags: html, css

I need to align my banner with the buttons, banner size is w:967  h:106, tried to directly add the image but it pushes all the buttons to the right.

This is what my code looks like so far:

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <img src="png"/>
        <ul class="fancyNav">
            <li id="home"><a href="index.php" class="homeIcon">Home</a></li>
            <li id="s"><a href="#s">Social</a></li>
            <li id="p"><a href="#p">Political</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.fancyNav{
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 16%;
    margin-left: 170px;
}
```

Site link: http://mops.pcriot.com/main.html

Comment: .fancyNav{display: block;} use this instead inline-block

Comment: You've gotten answers which suggest that the `padding` or `width` or `top` or `margin` be changed... but these are all hacks/work-arounds for the use of `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by `display: inline-block;` which behaves like this:

```
Displays an element as an inline-level block container.
The inside of this block is formatted as block-level box,
and the element itself is formatted as an inline-level box.
```

Using `display: block` will solve this, but then you may need to do more to align the navigation. Anything with `inline` in it, will cause what you're seeing.

Here are your other options for the `display:` property:

- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: I saw you made a fix to your site to use this answer, and the navigation is closer to what you want now. *Now* you may want to use width: 100% also, and keep display: block

Comment: Yep this fixed it, changed it to block, used center tag in html, neat. Thanks.

Comment: Cool! Now you need this: `.fancyNav li a { padding: 14px 35px; }` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
.fancNav {
    top: 110px;
}
```

adjust 110 to whatever looks best

Answer (score 0):

make some changes in your class

```
.fancyNav {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    top: 16%;
    margin-left: 170px;
    width: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Left Aligned** - Try removing:

```
.fancyNav {
    margin-left: 170px;
}
```

Then add:

```
.fancyNav {
    padding: 0;
}
```

**Center Aligned** - Do as above then add:

```
nav {
    margin-left: 170px;
}
```

or instead (probably better):

```
nav {
    width: 967px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```